# shell: file management according to the pattern in the name

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am dealing with a group of 12 filles located within the same directory. The names of the filles are given in multi-column format separated by _. Here are those 12 filles:

```
7000_01_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_05_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_09_lig_cne_767.dlg
7000_02_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_06_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_10_lig_cne_767.dlg
7000_03_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_07_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_11_lig_cne_767.dlg
7000_04_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_08_lig_cne_767.dlg 7000_12_lig_cne_767.dlg
```

Here the difference between the filles is given in the second column (from 1 to 12), keeping the same all of the name

I need to write a simple bash workflow suitable to loop over these file, creating a directory for each of the file (containing number from its second column, using as a pattern to descriminate bettween them) and then copying the particular file (for example 7000_04_lig_cne_767.dlg) into this directory (box_04). So each of the created subfolders should contain only 1 file. Here is my template:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set the name of folder with all DLG
FILES=$PWD/ALL_DLG

#name of the subfolder in which several subfolders (containing one of the input file) whould be created
output=${home}/sub_folders_to_analyse


# manage DLG filles
for i in ${FILES}/*.dlg       
do 
    # write some expression to take the file according to the number indicated within its second column
    # n = is the number occured in the second column;
    # manage the files to proper directories
    mkdir -p ${output}/"box_$n"
    cp "$i" ${output}/"box_$n"
done
```

I suppose n defined within for loop should contain some SED-based expression referred to the number of the second column (in the name of each file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your filename structure is rather regular, you can use `cut` to extract that field. **However**, as noted by @steeldriver, since your file path `$PWD/ALL_DLG` already contains one `_`, you either have to take that into account explicitly, or use the `basename` command to ensure the operation is applied only to the actual filename, not any path components:

```
n=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'_' -f 2)
```

would apply the `cut` command, using `_` as field delimiter, to the filename, and extract the second field (i.e. the number you want to identify). It would then write the result to the shell variable `n` via command substitution.